# Setting the background color of separate WPF ListBox items

Tags: wpf, background, listboxitem

I want to set the background color separately for each item in a WPF ListBox. e.g. If I am adding Widgets to the ListBox, I might set the background color for each one based on the type of widget. This must be done in code (not XAML) as I only know what the items are at run time.

I know how to use ItemContainerStyle to set the style for all items, but how do you do it separately for each item?

Comment: Specifying what kind of widget attributes would define the colour would have made this a lot better question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you do set **ItemContainerStyle**, using a **StyleSelector**.

[This example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.styleselector.aspx) at MSDN is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Loxxy and Robert. I went with a StyleSelector solution. I get access to the actual item in SelectStyle so I can set the background according to the contents of the item.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this.

One is to use a `StyleSelector`, as loxxy suggests.  This is pretty low on my list, because that kind of code is harder to read (well, find) and test than I'd like.

Another is to use a `DataTrigger` in the style.  This is simple, if (and only if) the items all implement a common property that can be used in the trigger.  You might be well served by implementing a wrapper class that exposes this common property, and contains the logic that figures out what value to assign to the property based on the object it's wrapping.  (Whether or not this is easier than a `StyleSelector` is certainly arguable.)

If the items are really and truly heterogeneous, you can accomplish the result by using data templates, e.g.:

```
<ListBox.Resources>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Foo}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding FooText}" Background="Red"/>
   </DataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Bar}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding BarText}" Background="Yellow"/>
   </DataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Baz}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding BazText}" Background="PapayaWhip"/>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.Resources>
```

etc.  This would generally be my first choice, but your question doesn't really explain enough about the circumstances to know if it's the right way to go or not.